# MVC 5 website with subscriptions/packages

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

**Scenario:**
I am in the process of creating a website (offering a service) where users will have to buy a subscription/package in order to use the website. These subscriptions are essentially products and based on the subscription type, the users will have access to different stuff. I only need two subscription types. An example would be like Pluralsight where you can buy STANDARD or PLUS subscriptions and you have access to files only if you have the PLUS subscription.

**Technology:**
I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 and Entity Framework for database access.

**So far:**
I have been thinking to implement it using roles/claims where each role define a specific type of subscriptions. Upon buying a subscription, the user will be given the coresponding role. But I am just not sure how such a problem is generally solved and I want to do it the right way.

Please help me in the right direction.
Thank you